# Using a dynamic table header as a variable in a VBA formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to enter a formula into a cell using VBA.  The formula needs to take in the column header of a separate table.

I have tried taking the column header as a value using the `Cells.Value` function.

```
Value1 = DSheet.Cells(1, 14).Value
For i = 2 To lastRowD
    DSheet.Cells(i, 14).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(SalesData[[Form]:[Form]], '" + DSheet.Name + "'RC13,SalesData[[#All],[" + Value1 + "]])"
Next
```

I am currently getting a Run-Time error 1004:

```
Select method of Range class failed
```

Comment: Use `&` instead of `+` to concatenate strings in your formula.

Comment: What is `DSheet` and where do you `Set` it?

Comment: `DSheet.Name + "'RC13` should be `DSheet.Name + "'!RC13,`

Comment: ...and just use `DSheet.Cells(i, 14).FormulaR1C1 = ...` no need to select anything here.  Your current code may be failing because DSheet isn't active: you can't select a range on a non-active sheet.